# Not able to mock GET request in cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

**x.spec.js**

```
before(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/dashboard/v1/public/api/allMachineStatus',
        headers: {
            "access-control-allow-credentials": true,
            "authorization": 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXiOjE1OTI0MDU5NjMsImV4cCI6MTU5NDk5Nzk2MywiaWQiOiIxMDAwIiwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.JaIUHy85pIZ_rulJCZXutqZXeC_4_wlVFa4z3I-8kO0'
        },
        response: 'fixture:allMachinesStatus'
    })
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('[data-testid="side-bar')
        .contains('Live Status')
        .click()

});
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.wait(100)
})

context("it should check headings",()=>{
    it("should check some heading",()=>{
        cy.get('[data-testid="refill-status-heading-live-status"]')
    })
    
})
```

Above is the test code and

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "machine_id": "...",
            "total_units": 550,
            "total_price": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is in allMachinesStatus.json 
When i load page i make **GET** request but i can not see that request in cypress logs

[image]

So the code here **x.spec.js** is also not mocking it. I am able to mock POST request but this get request is on page load and i dont know why its failing.

---

I have post request 
 (timings in response headers are)

```
   **..getPaymentMethods** - date: Sat, 20 Jun 2020 16:04:14 GMT // post request
    **...allMachineStatus** - date: Sat, 20 Jun 2020 16:04:13 GMT // get request that is not showing up on cy browser
```

Comment: Can you also check the request in the browser `Network` tab to make sure if the `Get` request is only missing from the 'cypress logs'?

Comment: @Sree.Bh I verify that in network tab call to same api is going and able to get response also

Comment: And what is the order in which you see the `same api` in network tab with respect to the `post` requests in the cypress log screenshot that you have shared?

Comment: @Sree.Bh hey i think timings will be the cause. As the get request is going on page load. What we do about that ? also i have checked twice get request response always come first.